What is this surface feature near Shackleton crater classified as?
I was looking at a map of the lunar South Pole and the surrounding area when I noticed the rectangular/elongated feature just to the left and below centerline of Shackleton crater in the below image:

This does not seem to be the Shackleton-de Gerlache connecting ridge or indeed anything marked on NASA landing site maps for the Artemis program, but I am unsure how to classify it as it seems unusually shaped for a depression or crater (sharp sides, long and leads into Shackleton itself).
Any ideas for what it might represent geologically?

Could you like outline the feature you're asking about in red or something?  I see two parallel ridges coming off Shackleton at just below the 9:00 position with a low point between them, but I'm not sure that's what you're pointing at.

Did you check both Artemis and Apollo? Or literally any other lunar exploration program, human or otherwise?

@DarthPseudonym Yes. That area is what I am pointing at. I will update the picture.

This is the Artemis landing site map from NASA that I'm familiar with, cut down a bit to show just the area of interest:

Now, that image shows Shackleton left of deGerlache, so obviously it's from the opposite direction to the one you're using, and at a more extreme angle. However, if we flip your photo to roughly match up:

I think it's very clear that the feature you're pointing at is indeed what NASA has identified as the "connecting ridge" on their map. It's a ridgeline, then a valley, and the other side of the valley is the lip of that smaller distorted crater between Shackleton and deGerlache.

OK. I was confused because the whole area seemed to consist of two ridgelines, not one, so I assumed there was a graphical error and NASA was referring to one or the other as connecting.

Thank you so much for your answer. Especially in the absence of additional views I am checking this (don't know if I should wait longer.) I was hoping this might be a lava tube or something but no dice.

@Lelu usually it’s recommended to wait a day or so, for people from different time zones/etc to swing by to take a look. In this case it’s pretty clear that this fully answers the question. But in general it doesn’t hurt to leave a bit more time for answers to come in.

@Lelu I usually wait at least a few days to a week, there are also once/weekly visitors. Then the "bump" to the active queue when an answer is accepted brings new visibility and often an upvote or two more for the answer(s). The only danger is waiting too long and then forgetting.

The area  is named the “Shackleton connecting ridge” and the  “Connecting Ridge Extension” according to https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/5013 video https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a000000/a005000/a005013/group1_1080p30.mp4

I have only unfounded speculation for its origin. It may be a partially obliterated old crater rim. Topographic maps of the Lunar south pole show many old, partially obliterated, crater rims.

The eye of faith can assemble unrelated features into even more rim fragments, the same way stars are assembled into constellations of completely unrelated stars.
If you play this game with the topography around the Shackleton crater, many elevated features appear to be at the intersections of “ghost crater” rims, as you would expect.
https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/lunar-south-pole-atlas/maps/SPole_87p5S_LOLA-PSR-Contours_v20190515.pdf
